# Use of HAVING in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table from which I need to select all persons that have a first name that is not unique and that that set should be selected only if among the persons with a similar first name, all have a different last name.

Example:

```
FirstN    LastN
Bill      Clinton
Bill      Cosby
Bill      Maher
Elvis     Presley
Elvis     Presley
Largo     Winch
```

I want to obtain

```
FirstN    LastN
Bill      Clinton
```

or

```
FirstN    LastN
Bill      Clinton
Bill      Cosby
Bill      Maher
```

I tried this but it does not return what I want.

```
SELECT * FROM Ids
GROUP BY FirstN, LastN
HAVING (COUNT(FirstN)>1 AND COUNT(LastN)=1))
```

[Edited my post after Aleandre P. Lavasseur remark]

Comment: Try concatenating first and last name.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
WITH duplicates AS (
  SELECT firstn --, COUNT(*), COUNT(DISTINCT lastn)
    FROM ids
    GROUP BY firstn
    HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(DISTINCT lastn)
       AND COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT a.firstn, a.lastn
  FROM ids a INNER JOIN duplicates b ON (a.firstn = b.firstn)
  ORDER BY a.firstn, a.lastn
```

If mysql does not support WITH, then inner query:

```
SELECT a.firstn, a.lastn
  FROM ids a
      ,(SELECT firstn --, COUNT(*), COUNT(DISTINCT lastn)
          FROM ids
          GROUP BY firstn
          HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(DISTINCT lastn)
             AND COUNT(*) > 1
        ) b
  WHERE a.firstn = b.firstn
  ORDER BY a.firstn, a.lastn
```

Comment: I think MySQL does not support `WITH`

Comment: You need aliases for `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(DISTINCT lastn)`. You could also drop them the select entirely

Comment: @ConradFrix Thanks. I removed the counts from the SELECT clause. I left them in for demonstration in case someone wants to try from the in out. I ran on Postgresql. No alias required there. Was unaware that alias would be required for mysql.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Glenn yeah MySQL syntax is different. That's why I always test MySQL answers on sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 3):

can you try this :

```
SELECT A.FirstN, B.LastN
FROM (
SELECT FirstN
FROM Ids
GROUP BY FirstN
HAVING (COUNT(FirstN)>1)
) AS A
INNER JOIN Ids B ON (A.FirstN = B.FirstN)
GROUP BY A.FirstN, B.LastN
HAVING COUNT(B.LastN)=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this...

```
SELECT FirstN + LastN as FullName, COUNT(*)
FROM Ids
GROUP BY FirstN + LastN
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Be sure to check for nulls since that'll nullify the concatenation.

Comment: Concatenating like that returns cero for me, shouldn't you use CONCAT(FirstN, LastN) for concatenation on My Sql?

Comment: Sorry. I'm a MS SQL guy. I was just suggesting concat as an option to the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to answer 2 but getting just first register where the name repeats (the first result you said you wanted to obtain)

```
select T.FirstN, T.LastN from  (
      select FirstN, LastN  from Ids
    group by FirstN, LastN
      having count(1) = 1) T
group by FirstN
having count(1) > 1;
```